# Regex - System Requirements

Tags: python, regex

I am learning regex and having difficulty when finding the pattern from the system requirements string below:

```
"OS: Windows® 7 Processor: Intel Core i3-9100 / AMD Ryzen 3 2300X Memory: 8 GB RAM Graphics: NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1050 Ti / AMD Radeon™ RX 560 (4GB VRAM) Storage: 60 GB available space"
```

I have done multiple ways but couldn't find any match. I wanted to group the result based on the colon(:) to a python dictionary like this:

```
    {
        'OS': 'Windows® 7',
        'Processor': 'Intel Core i3-9100 / AMD Ryzen 3 2300X',
        'Memory': '8 GB RAM Graphics: NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1050 Ti / AMD Radeon™ RX 560 (4GB VRAM)',
        'Storage': '60 GB available space'
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Here is my work: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nYSBD9/1). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) with `"(\w+):\s+(.*?)(?=$|\s*\w+:\s+)"`: A word, followed by a colon and spaces, then as little as possible of anything until either the end of string or another word followed by a colon and spaces.

minimal example:

```
s = "OS: Windows® 7 Processor: Intel Core i3-9100 / AMD Ryzen 3 2300X Memory: 8 GB RAM Graphics: NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1050 Ti / AMD Radeon™ RX 560 (4GB VRAM) Storage: 60 GB available space"

import re
d = dict(re.findall(r"(\w+):\s+(.*?)(?=$|\s*\w+:\s+)", s))
```

output:

```
{'OS': 'Windows® 7',
 'Processor': 'Intel Core i3-9100 / AMD Ryzen 3 2300X',
 'Memory': '8 GB RAM',
 'Graphics': 'NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1050 Ti / AMD Radeon™ RX 560 (4GB VRAM)',
 'Storage': '60 GB available space'}
```